# Merging two dataframes without duplicating the columns

Tags: pandas, dataframe, merge

I have two dataframes like this:

[image]

result dataframe is large and contains COMPANY names from bse dataframe but TOKEN and SYMBOL information is missing. I want to merge result dataframe with bse dataframe so that TOKEN and SYMBOL info of the companies in bse dataframe are added to the result dataframe.

When I merge, it duplicates the columns and rename them like this:

[image]

Problem is more like 'fill in the blanks'. I need to fill the TOKEN and SYMBOL information from bse dataframe into the corresponding rows of result dataframe.
I want to avoid renaming and duplication.

Can anyone help?

thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your merge code?

Comment: merge code added in question.

Comment: So missing values means there is no match, it means e.g. not exist `AXTEL IN` in `result`.

Comment: AXTEL IN (and other companies from bse) exists in result but without TOKEN and SYMBOL

Comment: problem is more like 'fill in the blanks'. I need to fill the TOKEN and SYMBOL information from bse dataframe into the corresponding rows of result dataframe.

Comment: Ok, is possible filter rows for see if exist `AXTEL IN` rows in both and then post `result.head().to_dict()` and `bse.head().to_dict()` ?

Comment: I tried a solution. made COMPANY as index and used result.update(bse). it seems to worked